# Where can I find the html.tpl.php $head variable content generation/markup?

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I am trying to locate where the variable $head is being generated from and more so the markup. Basically what file contains the markup for the $head variable.

My html.tpl.php is:

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="<?php print $language->language; ?>" version="XHTML+RDFa 1.0" dir="<?php print $language->dir; ?>"<?php print $rdf_namespaces; ?>>

<head profile="<?php print $grddl_profile; ?>">
  <?php print $head; ?>
  <title><?php print $head_title; ?></title>
  <?php print $styles; ?>
  <?php print $scripts; ?>
</head>
<body class="<?php print $classes; ?>" <?php print $attributes;?>>
  <div id="skip-link">
    <a href="#main-content" class="element-invisible element-focusable"><?php print t('Skip to main content'); ?></a>
  </div>
  <?php print $page_top; ?>
  <?php print $page; ?>
  <?php print $page_bottom; ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are declared in other files and it can depend - often they are in a template.php file for the theme (if it is a theme) and may be in the process_html function or one similar.

This $head one is very core and I you'll find that it comes from:

includes/theme.inc:

```
$variables['head'] = drupal_get_html_head();
```

That is inside the template_process_html() function.

Comment: Is this the same for search form then? Want to access the  want to access the raw html of the search block, have the search-block-form.tpl.php. It has a print $search_form that outputs the form. Want to get to the Raw HTML?

Comment: Yes so that would be in search.module file. But this is core, if you wanted to modify this you should be doing it in your own theme (in sites/all/themes), making your own .tpl.php files to override the core ones.

Answer (score 0):

I have never used Drupal at all, but most header files are located in a template folder inside includes, usually named header.tpl, i believe this is what you are asking where is the file for the header?`